# Convert group of value into single value within array

Tags: ruby

I have this kind of array:

```
a = ["2 3", "4 5 6"]
```

but I need to convert into this:

```
a = ["2", "3", "4", "5","6"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like "6" has gone [AWOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=AWOL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
a = ["2 3", "4 5 6"]
a.flat_map(&:split)
# => ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

This is more-or-less equivalent to this:

```
a.map {|s| s.split }.flatten
```

Comment: For anyone confused about `flat_map`, think of it this way. If we were to use `map` we'd get `a.map(&:split) #=> [["2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]`. `flat_map` merely splats each of the inner arrays: `[*["2", "3"], *["4", "5", "6"]] #=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]`. (Hmm, maybe it should be called `splat_map`.)

Comment: thanks @cary give useful information different between flap_map and map.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.join(' ').split
  #=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

Comment: I like how you think outside the box.

Comment: @spickermann, when one is late to the party and only crumbs remain, one has no choice. I often work on stale questions for that very reason--to exercise the little grey cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code :

```
arr = ["2 3", "4 5 6"]
op = []
arr.each {|ele| ele.split(' ').each {|val| op << val}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
a =  ["2 3", "4 5 6"]
b= []
   a.each do |a|
    b << a.split(" ")
   end
b.flatten!
```

Hope this will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this One-Liner:

```
a.map{|x| x.split(" ")}.flatten
```

Hope it  helps : )